# OCaml Bigarray: slower than builtin arrays?

Tags: multidimensional-array, ocaml

What are the downsides of using `Bigarray` when interfacing with C is not an issue? Are they slower, in particular for small 2D matrices?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just based on looking through the implementations, I'd say that bigarrays might be slower if you create large numbers of short-lived arrays.  It looks like the memory for them is managed outside the usual OCaml GC, which handles short-lived objects extremely well.

You also might find that accesses to bigarrays aren't inlined, whereas accesses to the built-in arrays would be.

On the other hand, built-in arrays are going to have an extra indirection for two-dimensions.

If the performance really matters, you'll probably have to benchmark your particular application.

Comment: There's also the fact that arrays are linear only for ints and floats. Any other type will be constructed as arrays of reference, so there might be a performance impact. On the other hand, bigarrays are always linear, although not living in the memory managed by the GC. For small matrices though, using arrays probably doesn't have any impact on performances.

Comment: @didierc “There's also the fact that arrays are linear only for ints and floats. Any other type will be constructed as arrays of reference, so there might be a performance impact” As opposed to Bigarrays doing what for non-int, non-float types? How did you manage to make the fact that Bigarrays can only hold ints and floats sound like an advantage?

Comment: OK. In my idiosyncratic benchmark, bigarrays are over two times slower than builtin arrays...

Answer (score 3):

The main downside is right there in the type - bigarrays can hold only small subset of primitive types

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention that for numerics the selection of types is OK, I mean, not a factor in question.

Comment: It would be nice if Bigarray admitted bool type, similarly to how it admits both ints and chars as a "view" of 8 bit values.